# motion detection from webcam to control mouse pointer using .NET

Tags: .net, mouse, driver, emgucv, motion-detection

My .NET application captures detects motion of a specific type of object from webcam. I am able to control movement of mouse within my form by translating the motion of the object. However I want to control the mouse movement outside my form, like some kind of virtual mouse.

What would be the best technique to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform click and move cursor outside the form through code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(int flags, int dX, int dY, int buttons, int extraInfo);
#region mouseConstants
const int MOUSE_MOVE = 0x00000001;
const int MOUSE_LEFTDOWN = 0x00000002;
const int MOUSE_LEFTUP = 0x00000004;
const int MOUSE_RIGHTDOWN = 0x00000008;
const int MOUSE_RIGHTUP = 0x00000010;
const int MOUSE_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x00000020;
const int MOUSE_MIDDLEUP = 0x00000040;
const int MOUSE_WHEEL = 0x00000800;
const int MOUSE_ABSOLUTE = 0x00008000; 
#endregion

private void performClick(int posX, int posY)
{
    Cursor.Position = new Point(posX, posY);  // to move the cursor at desired position
    mouse_event(MOUSE_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);  // to perform left mouse down
    mouse_event(MOUSE_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);    // to perform left mouse up
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try achieving this via Win API calls:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out Point pt);

 Point current;
 GetCursorPos(out current);
 SetCursorPos(current.X + 10, current.Y + 10);
```

This would work outside the application.

Comment: Thanks.. I just figured out it is also possible to control mouse events using user32.dll

Answer (score 1):

In C#:

```
//using System.Windows.Forms;
//using System.Drawing;
Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
```

Or if you want to move the mouse, rather than position it:

```
//using System.Windows.Forms;
//using System.Drawing;
Cursor.Position = Cursor.Position + new Size(deltaX, deltaY);
```

Comment: Thanks....
Is it also possible to perform click or double click outside the form through code???

Comment: @Naveeen: Yes, but it is a lot more complicated. Here is a good example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library